# how to use group by in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
   public JsonResult GetWeekTimeSheetData(DateTime Date)
    {
        try
        { 
            var thisWeekStart = Date.AddDays(-(int)Date.DayOfWeek);
            var thisWeekEnd = thisWeekStart.AddDays(7).AddSeconds(-1);
            List<Object> lstData = new List<object>();
           var Taskss = db.Tasks.Where(x => x.IsActive == true && x.TaskName != null).Select(x => x.TaskName);
            while (thisWeekStart.Date <= thisWeekEnd.Date)
            {
                double hourss = db.TimesheetData.Where(x => x.Date == thisWeekStart && x.Date != null).GroupBy(y => (double?)y.Hours) ?? 0;
                double hours = db.TimesheetData.Where(x => x.Date == thisWeekStart && x.Date != null).Sum(y => (double?)y.Hours) ?? 0;
                lstData.Add(new { DayName = thisWeekStart.ToString("dddd"), Hours = hours, TAskName=q });
                thisWeekStart = thisWeekStart.AddDays(1);
            }
            return Json(lstData);
```

My table is:

```
 TimeSheetDatas(Guid ID,double hours,DateTime Date,Guid TaskID,virtual 
 TimeSheet TimeSheet ).
 TimeSheets(Guid ID,DateTime StartDate,DateTime EndDate,List<TimeSheetData> 
 TimeSheetData).
 Tasks( String TaskName,string TaskDescription)
```

i want hourss =which is sum of hours of each task lie between thisweekstart and thisweekend.I have tried to write query but i dont know how to use groupby  function. To know what the question of mine juse see this

```
  double hourss = db.TimesheetData.Where(x => x.Date == thisWeekStart && 
  x.Date != null).GroupBy(y => (double?)y.Hours) ?? 0;
```

its wrong but i tried this. i just want sum of hours of each task which 
     is in TimeSheetDatas betwwen thisweekstart and thisweekend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try like this;

```
var timesCalculation = db.TimesheetData
    .GroupBy(x => x.Task)
    .Select(grp => new
    {
        Task = grp.Key.Task,
        HourSum = grp.Sum(x => (double?)x.Hour ?? 0)
    });
```

I am assuming that you have navigation property in the `TimesheetData` entity for `Task`.

Comment: Task = grp.Key.Task, what the meaning of this line..i have an error at place of task i am using TaskID at place of Task

Comment: Well, you don't have navigation property. You should define the Task property as navigation property in the TimesheetData entity. Another option is you can perform join but I strongly suggest you to create it as navigation property.

Comment: i have a navigation property @Rainman TaskID is the property in timesheetdatas

Comment: No, it is not. It suggest you to learn navigation properties.